# How to expose an asp.net core docker container to a public url?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

If I have a public url such as `https://dogsandcats.com` and I'd like to be able to connect to it from a deployed docker container to that server, how can I go about doing so?

Currently, I have the following Dockerfile for my .Net Core project:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MedicineInventoryManagement.dll"]
```

I am exposing port 8080 and when I visit localhost:8080 on my local environment, I can see my webserver distributing the application. I have mapped port 8080 on `https://dogsandcats.com` but it doesn't run as it does on my local computer.

Do I have to do something with the following code block in `Program.cs`?

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Or does the issue lie elsewhere?

Comment: by default dotnet core apps run on port 5000 tho and i dont see that you have used the UseUrls to chamge that. What so you see get when you try it from outside? And if i got it correctly, you are deploying your container on the server witht he public url and when you try to connect from outside it doesnt work?

Comment: When I use this container: aspnetcore-runtime, it runs on port 8000 by default. When I try to access the public website, I get a 503 Forbidden No server running to handle the request error. I think without docker asp.net core websites will run on port 5000 by default, but with this container it is different.

Answer (score 2):

The microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime image sets the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to http://+:80 which means that if you have not explicity set a URL in your application, via app.UseUrl in your Program.cs for example, then your application will be listening on port 80 inside the container.

https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/

Answer (score 0):

I would debug issues like these using a bottom up approach.

1. Do `docker ps` to check what ports does your container expose to the host and what ports does it bind to? Have a look under the ports column. You can also use the following command and provide your container name:

`docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID`

If a port is exposed as intended, there are a few things to check on the host. Now depending on how your environment is setup, the steps can differ but you'll see what I mean.

2. Start by looking into the firewall rules. For example, if you are on Ubuntu and have UFW enabled, check if the rules are configured to allow access to that Port. If you are behind a home/office router, you might want to open ports to let the public traffic come that port. If you are running a server like Apache/Nginx, I would check if my virtual hosts/server blocks are configured properly.
3. If you find that your ports are opened as expected, try accessing it using the public ip of your network. There is no point looking into the DNS records if we can't access it using the public IP of the machine. After all, that's what the DNS are pointing to. If you are unable to access I would go back to Step #2.

If Step#3 is all clear, then I would look into the DNS records and try to identify the issue.

To understand this process, here is a very high level overview of it. Try a bottom up approach so you can exactly pin point the issue you are stuck with.

[DNS] => [Public IP of your network] => [Hardware Firewall like router etc.] => [Nginx/Apache web server etc. if any] => [Machine's firewall like OS or third party] => Docker Host Port => Dotnet Core Port in the Container.

You could also using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) if you just want to test something quick for development purposes. That takes away the pain of Step#2 and Step#3 by setting up a proxy for you (specially when you are behind a strict firewall you don't control). I'm not associated to ngrok in any way. There are a few other alternatives to it as well.